# mysql jdbc communication exception

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc

I have a Java application which initially **reads 3 lakhs of data from my MYSQL** database.Then it **calls an API** using an **ExecutorService** with **newFixedThreadPool size=20**.
After getting the response from the API it is inserting the responses to my DB.It is working fine for first 2000 rows(nearby).After that I am getting an error like following.

> SQLError-com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The
>   driver was unable to create a connection due to an inability to
>   establish the client portion of a socket.
>
> This is usually caused by a limit on the number of sockets imposed by
>   the operating system. This limit is usually configurable.
>
> For Unix-based platforms, see the manual page for the 'ulimit'
>   command. Kernel or system reconfiguration may also be required.
>
> For Windows-based platforms, see Microsoft Knowledge Base Article
>   196271 (Q196271).

Anyone could help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Well, if it is indeed caused by the number of connections opened, what you need is connection pooling to restrict the number of connections to a discret, reasonable number, something like an aproximation to the number of concurrent users that your application may have.

Comment: How are you managing db connections, are they released when not in use?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by increasing the # of sockets that can be opened in Windows:

1. From the Windows Start menu, run the regedit.exe application
2. In the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` directory, create a new `DWORD` value named `MaxUserPort` with a decimal value of 65,000 (the default is 5,000)
3. After closing the regedit application, restart your computer.

(See also [Increasing the number of Windows sockets or ports](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.0.0?topic=server-increasing-number-windows-sockets-ports), [Maximum Socket Connections](https://sockettools.com/kb/maximum-socket-connections/#:%7E:text=The%20theoretical%20maximum%20for%20Windows,2G%20or%20more%20of%20RAM))

**A note of caution:** When an application is using more than 5,000 socket connections, that may be an indication that system resources are not being used in a sustainable way. It would be good to investigate the root cause for why so many sockets are being opened simultaneously.